# Using $this for variables in a zf2 view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Apparently, the correct way to pass a variable from a controller to a view in ZF2 is:

```
return new ViewModel(array(
        'myVar' => "Hello World",
    ));
```

and the way to display the variable is:

```
echo $this->myVar;
```

However, I've found that this also works:

```
echo $myVar;
```

Is there any reason to use `$this->` if it doesn't seem to be needed?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more code. Where is `$myVar` stored? In what scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `$this` in "view" context remains with its intended purpose.
 Within view file in will always indicate to the current view object(view model).
Though you can still access view variables in such way: `echo $myVar;`.
*BUT*, such a variable can be easily overwritten within view content and, therefore, become a 'local' variable with a custom value. 
Here is some practical demonstration:
Let's we have `IndexController.php` and the view file `index.phtml` respectively.

**IndexController.php**:

```
class General_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    ...
    public function indexAction() {
        ...
        $this->view->myVar = "value from contr-er";

    }
    ...

}
```

**index.phtml**:

```
<?php $myVar = "myvar in view"; ?>
<?php var_dump($myVar); ?>
<?php var_dump($this->myVar); ?>
.... // html markup
```

The output will be:

```
string 'myvar in view' (length=13)
string 'value from contr-er' (length=19)
```

Though `$this->myVar` can also be overwritten in view, however `$this` as view object lets you keep clear and direct relation with all variables(values) passed from controller.